# How can I make NerdTree update root to the current directory when I change directory with :cd?

Tags: neovim

I found out that when I change directory with `:cd`, the root directory of NerdTree is not affected. How can I make NerdTree change its root when I use `:cd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your best bet is to utilize the command `:NERDTreeCWD`:

```
:NERDTreeCWD                                                      *:NERDTreeCWD*
    Change the NERDTree root to the current working directory.  If no
    NERDTree exists for this tab, a new one is opened.
```

Now you can't override `:cd` but you could create a custom command that's close...it just has to start with a capital letter:

```
:com! -nargs=1 -bar -complete=dir Cd :cd <args> | NERDTreeCWD
```

Use just like `:cd`...

```
:Cd /some/path
```

**Never mind all that...this just occurred to me and is much better IMO.**

There is an [auto command event triggered by directory change](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#DirChanged)

```
augroup DIRCHANGE
    au!
    autocmd DirChanged global :NERDTreeCWD
augroup END
```

That's it.

Note that this is only for the global directory change of `:cd`. To have this work with `:lcd` you'd change `global` to `window` or you could include both by separating them with commas. Full list:

```
"window"  to trigger on `:lcd`
"tabpage" to trigger on `:tcd`
"global"  to trigger on `:cd`
"auto"    to trigger on 'autochdir'.
"drop"    to trigger on editing a file
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you!